# Is there a way to dump the objects in memory from a running ruby process?

Tags: ruby, heap-memory

Killing the processs while obtaining this information would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the more hardcore there is also [BleakHouse](http://blog.evanweaver.com/files/doc/fauna/bleak_house/files/README.html) which gives you a special custom-compiled copy of ruby with better memory leak tracking powarz

Comment: Does bleak house work for others? I tried it and it just dumps core on anything but the most trivial program. This is ruby 1.8.6 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and-dirty way would be `ObjectSpace.each_object{|e| p e}`. You could do some tests to determine what you wanted to keep, or Marshal the objects.

Answer (score 2):

For 1.9.2/1.9.3 there's heap_dump gem, it can be injected into a running process using gdb (but more stable was is to include it in process itself, no performance overhead)

It dumps references to objects, not objects themselves, but this is usable if you're into fighting leaks